# Calculate the Expected Return in the Limit as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, expectation

Let's say I have some hypothetical investment which can earn me some return $i$, where $i$ is a random variable.  After $n$ periods, my expected return on my investment is:

$$
E[((1+i_1)(1+i_2)(1+i_3)\cdots(1+i_n))^{1/n}]
$$

$$
=E[(1+i_1)^{1/n}(1+i_2)^{1/n}(1+i_3)^{1/n}\cdots(1+i_n)^{1/n}]
$$

Since the returns are all independent of each other (we will assume), then we can simplify:

$$
=E[(1+i)^{1/n}]^{n}
$$
Since the expectation has $n$ embedded in it, it will depend on the value of $n$.  My question is, what does this expression look like as $n$ goes to infinity:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} E[(1+i)^{1/n}]^{n}
$$

I suspect that the answer is the Geometric Mean of $1+i$:
$$
e^{E[ln(1+i)]}
$$

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to prove this?

Comment: I think it may depend on the distribution of $i$ as well

Comment: $$E\left(e^{X/n}\right)^n=E\left(1+X/n+o(1/n)\right)^n{} =\left(1+E(X)/n+o(1/n)\right)^n\to e^{E(X)}\qquad X=\log(1+i)$$